# Is there any difference between "switch" and "swap"?

Tags: differences, verbs

Is there any difference between *switch* and *swap*?

Comment: Depending on the research you've done, there might be differences in specialist usage. With no research, there's no useful difference. What did your dictionaries, thesauruses or search engines leave unclear, please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Swap* means "exchange", while *switch* means "change".

When you *swap* something, you replace something with something else:

> house swap, wife swap

When you *switch* something, you move from something to something else:

> Switch language, switch flight

Comment: `Swap` (to me) implies replacing some physical object with another. `Switch` means changes from some property, location, or attribute to another.

Comment: Also, *swapping* usually implies *exactly two entities* having a role in the play.

Comment: For swap, I think "interchange" is better word than "exchange". See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34545/interchange-and-exchange

Comment: Whatever else, I think "interchange" has no place here. Either "swap" or "switch" might mean "change" but doesn't "interchange" broadly mean something like "junction" or "cross-over"?

Answer (score 1):

In "ordinary" usage probably not.

In technical use there are differences depending on the field

Comment: For instance, <code>switch</code> is a construct in some programming languages, and "swapping" in programming is swapping the values of two variables.

Answer (score -1):

Switching simply means replacing something with something else, or moving from one state to another state. Here is an example: John switched off the lights; it means lights were on and John changed the state from on to off.

Swap normally happens between two people, they want to give and take something to/from each other, usually the items or the actions are identical, although this rule is not set in stone. Example: Feel free to swap out certain ingredients in recipes if you feel like it.

See the difference ?
Anyway you could check out my site **https://bigben.academy/how-to-correctly-use-swap-switch-change-and-exchange/** to have a better understanding.

Comment: EL&U focuses on authoritative answers from respected sources. This answer does not provide that. Promotion of personal commerical websites is also frowned upon.

Comment: Answers saying "look elsewhere" are [not welcome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), I'm afraid. Answers to Stack Exchange questions are expected to be complete in themselves. Disregarding the link, this answer is actually unclear.