# "Interchange" and "exchange"

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering if interchange and exchange are equivalent and can be used interchangeably or exchangeably (okay this is an example already)?
What are the differences between their prefixes, *inter-* and *ex-*?

> It is common for XML to be used in interchanging data over the Internet.

Answer (score 7):

Interchanging data would be swapping one piece of data for another (changing their positions). It is more specific than exchanging data, which just means that data is going back and forth.
You should say "exchange" here.

In general, data is not interchanged, because what you send is a copy. There are situations where interchange might be correct (eg: atomically swapping two memory locations, so what was in A is now in B, and vice versa) but even here "exchange" or "swap" is more common terminology.

Comment: I think @kiamlaluno's sentence is clearer with regard to *exchange* "Exchange refers to the act of giving one thing and receiving another (especially of the same type or value) in return"

Answer (score 1):

*Interchange*, as verb, means

- (of two or more people) exchange things with each other
- (of a thing) be able to be exchanged with another

As noun, *interchange* means

- the action of interchanging things, especially information
- an exchange of words
- alternation

*Exchange* refers to the act of giving one thing and receiving another (especially of the same type or value) in return.

The difference beetwen *inter-* and *ex-* is that the first prefix means "between, among" and the latter means "out."

Answer (score 1):

I also had this question, there was no answer that satisfied me (this question included). It really is tricky. But the following works for me.

Exchange implies there is a back and forth:

1. A gives B some C
2. B gives A some D

Interchange implies there is no back and forth. But rather is the idea of or the result of an exchange happening. There is no middle step of give and take.

1. B now has C, where A had it before
2. A now has D, where B had it before

This is further exemplified by our usage of "interchangeably", one thing can be replaced by another with no noticeable effect. While exchange implies there is a transaction.

I think a lot of confusion when trying to understand this word is the fact that people don't understand it and thus misuse it, making us unsure of what the correct meaning is.

Answer (score 0):

If overthinking needed a poster child, this is it....the concept of exchange is simple. Buy a pair of sneakers, take back and get another pair.... it's an exchange because you're giving something then getting something different in return. Would be considered an interchange if you take back the a pair originally bought and are given back the exact same pair. It's because no 2 things are exactly the same. An interchange is moving the exact same thing one through the other with zero change. Like carrying a football and passing it to another who carries the same football across the finish line.

Comment: I'm not sure that your particular definition of _interchange_ follows the usage of the word in the IT context.

Answer (score 0):

I list the most specific use of each word:

**Interchange:** to put each of two things in the place of the other (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English).

**Exchange:** to give something to someone while this person gives something to me.